# Obtener valor de una variable

Tags: php, jquery

Tengo la variable $reporteDetalle
quiero mandarla a llamar desde otro archivo PHP posteriormente tengo escrita una condición con esa variable pero,

> quiero saber como obtener el valor que se le asigno a esa variable ya
>   sea 0 o 1

```
        <?
        $reporteDetalle = (int) $_POST['reporteDetalle'];
        ?>
        <label>Tipo de Reporte</label>
<select name="reporteDetalle" id="reporteDetalle">
        <option value="0" <? if($reporteDetalle == 0 )  echo ' selected:'; ?>>Detallado </option>
        <option value="1" <? if($reporteDetalle == 1) echo ' selected:'; ?>>Global </option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <?
        $col = $col + 2;
        $jsvars .= 'var reporteDetalle = $("#reporteDetalle").val();
        ';
        if($fcount!==1) $params .= ',';
        $params .= 'reporteDetalle';
        $freporteDetalle = false;

}
```

Comment: No se entiende exactamente lo que preguntas. ¿Donde esta la variable `$tipoReporte `? En el código no se ve.

Comment: @JDev mira en el option dentro del if

Comment: En el `option` pone `$reporteDetalle` no `$tipoReporte`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira si obtener el valor de la variable es lo que quieres y posteriormente mandar ese valor, podrías usar jquery junto con Ajax, espero y te sirva este ejemplo.

ejemplo.php

```html
<html>

<head>

  <title></title>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <label>Tipo de Reporte</label>
  <select name="reporteDetalle" id="reporteDetalle">
    <option value="0" <? if($reporteDetalle==0 ) echo ' selected:'; ?>>Detallado </option>
    <option value="1" <? if($reporteDetalle==1 ) echo ' selected:'; ?>>Global </option>
  </select>

  <div id="resultado" style="width: 100px; height: 20px; background: #ccf; padding: 20px;"></div>


  <script>
    $('#reporteDetalle').on('change', function() {

      $.ajax({
        data: {
          "parametro1": $("#reporteDetalle").val()
        },
        url: 'respuesta.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
          $("#resultado").html(response);
        }
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

respuesta.php

```html
<?php 
$resultado = $_POST['parametro1']; 
echo $resultado;
?>
```